# How to get colaperation in github/

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I just finished my django and react course and now I'm trying to `practice web stack`by `cloning an app called notion.so.` I just started with that project but I'm looking for who want share or learn with me. So if anyone from `stackoverflow` like this idea please join me, also if you know more about `social networks` for such purposes inform me as well.
my project repo: https://github.com/aliplutus/Learning-webstack-from-cloning-notion.so

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not related to programming as defined in the help center. Looking for collaborators on a project is off-topic here.

Comment: you mean like.. stackoverflow should by only for errors and debugging questions?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .